# Knots and reducible spectra $\mathbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]/I$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $I=(y^2-x^3-x^2)$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. I don't know why $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I)$ is irreducible but $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]/I)$ is reducible. Do you know how can I see this or can you give me some reference about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $y^2 - x^3 - x^2$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$; one way to see this is to use Eisenstein's criterion with the polynomial $x + 1$. On the other hand the polynomial $y^2 - x^3 - x^2$ is reducible in the power series ring:

> > **Hint:** What is the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{x+1}$?

Comment: But I havn't $a_0$ in $(y^2-x^3-x^2)$... so $(x+1)^2 | 0$...

Comment: And what is the geometric interpretation of this fact?

Comment: @ArturStuart Geometrical meaning is that there are 2 branches of the curve passing through $(0,0)$ (reducibility in the ring of power series), but the curve minus singular points (such as $(0,0)$) is connected (irreducibility in the polynomial ring). Power series see locally, polynomials globally. (As for Eisenstein, the hint was to replace $x$ with $t-1$ (so that $t=x+1$))

Comment: @user8268 I'm sorry... do you know some reference about this? because I'd like to know if formal series are a domain, their spec etc...